# Don't pass OAuth in POST variables - PHP OAuth Pecl library

Tags: php, oauth

I am working with a third party service that requires me to authenticate through OAuth1 to make requests. I can successfully authenticate and get data back with most of their calls using GET, however some calls they require POST and this is where the problem lies. To authenticate I am using the below:

```
$oauth = new OAuth(MY_KEY,MY_SECRET);
$oauth->setNonce(rand());    
$oauth->setToken('','');
```

Then for a GET call I am doing something like below:

```
$array = array(
    'partnerId'=>'1234'
    );

$call = $oauth->fetch("https://domain.co.uk/api/getInfo/",$array);
$data = $oauth->getLastResponse();
```

This all works perfectly, and I can print out the $data

However with POST calls:

```
$oauth = new OAuth(MY_KEY,MY_SECRET);
$oauth->setNonce(rand());    
$oauth->setToken('','');
$oauth->enableDebug();
$oauth->setAuthType(OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION);

$array = array(
    'rid' => "$restaurantId",
    'datetime' => "$datetime",
    'partysize' => $covers,
    'timesecurityID' => "$securityId",
    'resultskey' => "$resultskey"
);

$call = $oauth->fetch("https://domain.co.uk/api/booking/?pid=1234&st=0",$array,OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST);
$data = $oauth->getLastResponse();
```

I keep getting the error: `Invalid Consumer Signature`

Speaking to their tech guy he suggested

> Your sbs value indicates that you’re signing with all of the POST
>   parameters, whereas you only need to sign with the query string.  In
>   this case it would be “pid=1234&st=0”.  Unfortunately, I’m not
>   familiar with the PHP libs and don’t have any recommendations on how
>   to alter the behavior.

and also mentioned common previous problems with a PHP implementation are:

1. The PHP HTTP lib will drop the query string once the method is
   changed from GET to POST.
2. The PHP oAuth lib will use the post data
   to sign the request rather than the query string or maybe both.

If I dump out the headers I get:

```
[sbs] => POST&https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.co.uk%2Fapi%2Fbooking%2F&datetime%3D2013-02-21T10%253A30%253A00%26oauth_consumer_key%3DMySiteV3TT%26oauth_nonce%3D1213111151%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1360835965%26oauth_token%3D%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26partysize%3D2%26pid%3D1531%26resultskey%3DfoqgEnYK%25252bIzRd6BV3T8eGQ%25253d%25253d%26rid%3D31852%26st%3D0%26timesecurityID%3D349367809
[headers_sent] => POST /api/booking/?pid=1234&st=0 HTTP/1.1
```

It looks like it is sending the OAuth data with the rest of the post, I just want this sent in the Authorization header (which it is also sending)

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="MySite",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_nonce="1772854358",oauth_timestamp="1360768712",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="",oauth_signature="2%2B7xb%2BJ5cdbUDC5UHfsdfsNpFM1pE%3D"
```

So I think I need to strip the OAuth data from the post request but keep it as a Authorization Header but just can't find the magic way to do that!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this.  In fetch(), try urlencoding your $array and passing it in as a string of the form:

```
rid=[restaurantId]&datetime=[datetime]&...
```

Also give the header (final parameter of fetch()):

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```